# Arduino Every TCCR1A 'not declared in this scope'

Tags: arduino

I have created a class that outputs a 25K PWM signal on either pin 9 or pin 10 for the Arduino Nano. And on the Nano it works perfectly. However if I change the board to "Arduino Every" I get `'TCCR1A' was not declared in this scope'`. I am including `<Arduino.h>` but it seams these defines are non-existing for the Arduino Every board? This board is suppose to be compatible with the Nano, why are these defines not found then?

My code (note: separate C++ file, so its not the sketch file) :

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include "HixPinPWM25KHz.h"

HixPinPWM25KHz::HixPinPWM25KHz(int nPinNumber): HixPin(nPinNumber) {
}

void HixPinPWM25KHz::begin() {
  //25KHz PWM only supported on ping 9 and 10
  if ( (m_nPinNumber != 9) && (m_nPinNumber != 10) ) {
    return;
  }
  // Configure Timer 1 for PWM @ 25 kHz.
  TCCR1A = 0;           // undo the configuration done by...
  TCCR1B = 0;           // ...the Arduino core library
  TCNT1  = 0;           // reset timer
  TCCR1A = _BV(COM1A1)  // non-inverted PWM on ch. A
           | _BV(COM1B1)  // same on ch; B
           | _BV(WGM11);  // mode 10: ph. correct PWM, TOP = ICR1
  TCCR1B = _BV(WGM13)   // ditto
           | _BV(CS10);   // prescaler = 1
  ICR1   = 320;         // TOP = 320
  pinMode(m_nPinNumber, OUTPUT);
  analogWrite(50);
}

void HixPinPWM25KHz::analogWrite(float percent) {
  int value = (int) ( (percent * (float)320) / (float)100 );
  switch (m_nPinNumber) {
    case 9:
      OCR1A = value;
      break;
    case 10:
      OCR1B = value;
      break;
    default:
      // no other pin will work
      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: this is for 'classic' ATmega. the MCU on Every doesn't have this registers

Comment: How to setup 25k pwm in the every then? Its suppose to be arduino nano compkiant...

Comment: if you want classic Nano, buy a classic Nano.

Comment: Nano Every has ATmega4809. To use the registers, read the datasheet

Comment: I have a classic nano but every is way cheaper so for prototyping want to switch :)

Comment: try the compatibility mode in Tools menu

Comment: For 25k pwm will launch seperate question. Can you formulate an answer so I can accept it in SO?

Comment: better delete the question and ask the next one on Arduino Stack Exchage

Comment: See https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/68308/arduino-every-25k-pwm-signal